# Custom Css Page Preloader in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

i made a custom css animation for a website so it shows every time a page is loading. 
The problem is i cant find a way to use this animation in a wordpress site.

I am an experience wordpress user and was hoping that after the animation was done it would be really easy to do this but i cant find the answer.

Here is my snippet. How do i use it in wordpress?

```css
#cssload-loader {
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 88px;
}
#cssload-loader ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 88px;
 height: 63px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 0;
 height: 10px;
}
#cssload-loader ul li {
 position: absolute;
 width: 8px;
 height: 0;
 background-color: #154093;
 bottom: 0;
}


#cssload-loader li:nth-child(1) {
 left: 0;
 animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease infinite 0;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease infinite 0;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease infinite 0;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease infinite 0;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease infinite 0;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(2) {
 left: 15px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(3) {
 left: 29px;
 animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.23s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.23s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.23s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.23s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.23s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(4) {
 left: 44px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(5) {
 left: 58px;
 animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(6) {
 left: 73px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.58s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.58s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.58s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.58s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.58s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(7) {
 left: 87px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.12s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(8) {
 left: 101px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.23s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.23s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.23s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.23s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease infinite 0.23s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(9) {
 left: 115px;
 animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence2 1.15s ease-in infinite 0.35s;
}
#cssload-loader li:nth-child(10) {
 left: 129px;
 animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -o-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -ms-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
  -moz-animation: cssload-sequence1 1.15s ease-in-out infinite 0.46s;
}
@keyframes cssload-sequence1 {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 49px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-sequence1 {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 49px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-sequence1 {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 49px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-sequence1 {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 49px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-sequence1 {
 0% {
  height: 10px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 49px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 10px;
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-sequence2 {
 0% {
  height: 19px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 63px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 19px;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-sequence2 {
 0% {
  height: 19px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 63px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 19px;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-sequence2 {
 0% {
  height: 19px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 63px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 19px;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-sequence2 {
 0% {
  height: 19px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 63px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 19px;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-sequence2 {
 0% {
  height: 19px;
 }
 50% {
  height: 63px;
 }
 100% {
  height: 19px;
 }
}
```

```html
<body style="padding:100px;">
    <div id="cssload-loader" style="margin: 0 auto;">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? It looks fine...

Comment: I edited to make it more clear. I dont need help with the css, i need help to put it into a wordpress site.